# Unit stuck, can't do anything but delete it

Tags: civilization-5

The weird thing is, that I can't even choose to "do nothing"!
I can only Gift it, delete it or start a war. Why don't I have the "do nothing" option?
[image: Capture.]

Comment: Isn't "space" the key for passing a unit's turn?  Or you could try "H" for holding position.

Comment: Hard to see, but its because it ended up on the same tile as another unit that it didn't know had existed when it started its move, and due to 1UPT, it has to move. Really annoying when that happens, and nothing you can do about it except to get rid of it.

Comment: Damn, stupid AI that got there in the first place. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Affine You should make that an answer so that it can be voted on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you can see above the mini-map in the lower right-hand corner, your unit is stacked with another unit and cannot remain in that tile. However, the Galleass cannot enter ocean tiles, but that's the only tile within one move of its current position, and it only has one movement point left this turn.

In short, you're stuck and must either delete or gift the unit or declare war on La Venta. I'm really curious what would happen if you DoW since you cannot remain on the same tile as the other unit.

Comment: @user52549 Declare a War?

Comment: Yes, DoW means Declaration of War and is often used as a verb on Civ forums.

Answer (score 1):

This is strange. It appears that because of your lack of mobility and because you can't seem to toggle the "Do Nothing" button I would assume that (it has happened rarely) that your unit has moved on top of another unit that wasn't shown at the beginning of your turn. Only way to fix it is to wait until the other player moves their unit.

Comment: He can't wait until the other player moves their unit; that would require ending his turn, but the game is very strict about not letting a player end turn while one of their units is stacked with something else.